# Updating problem[Broken package]

Tags: updates, package-management

I am not able to update software by package manager and also by terminal it show the following message:

```
Error:Bokencount>0
```

Well i tried package manager so it says me to fix broken package first so i went in Package tab and clicked repair broken packages then it started showing zero broken package but now it started showing new error:

```
**E: /var/cache/apt/archives/burg-theme-lightness_0.5.0-1_all.deb: subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 2**
```

Answer (score 0):

Repair broken software package on ubuntu 12.04 and ubuntu 12.10, 
To solve broken package problem on Ubuntu, you need to purge it which is related to PPA or software source. There are several way to solve this problem.

1. Cleaning using two ways command.

   sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get update
2. If you fail using the first command, try to use this one:

   dpkg --configure -a
3. Try this command if you failed to remove broken package using the second command:

   apt-get install -f

The last command will help you to remove all broken package.